# How to use both mysql & postgresql extensions in Druid?

Tags: druid, druid-extensions

Druid only allows one of `mysql-metadata-storage` or `postgresql-metadata-storage` in the extensions `loadList`. If we try to add both, it fails.
But we have a use case where we are using mysql for metadata storage, and postgres for lookups and need to use both.

```
druid.extensions.loadList=["druid-s3-extensions","druid-kafka-indexing-service","druid-multi-stage-query","druid-histogram","druid-kinesis-indexing-service","clarity-emitter","druid-parquet-extensions","druid-azure-extensions","druid-datasketches","mysql-metadata-storage","postgresql-metadata-storage","druid-lookups-cached-global"]
```

This does not work. It only accepts either mysql or postgresql extension.

How do I add postgres Driver to Druid's classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Apache Druid's `docker` or `helm` charts, Druid uses this file as the Docker entrypoint.

https://github.com/apache/druid/blob/master/distribution/docker/druid.sh#L43

Use this environment variable to provide additional jars to Druid classpath (in our case, we need to pass the postgresql driver jar).

```
DRUID_ADDITIONAL_CLASSPATH: "/opt/druid/extensions/postgresql-metadata-storage/postgresql-42.4.3.jar"
```

This can also be passed in helm's `values.yaml` in `configVars` - https://github.com/apache/druid/blob/master/helm/druid/values.yaml#L34.

All values here are passed as env variables to Druid.

So, use the above variable to include Postgresql driver jar in classpath while mysql can simply be loaded as an standard extension.

```
druid_extensions_loadList: '[..., "mysql-metadata-storage"]
```